# Sending key value pairs to a storage server

Tags: java, byte

My task is to send key value pairs as bytes to a storage server.

The current approach I take is to send everything (key, value) as one message to the server. I am planning to use a delimiter for the separation between key and value. Is this the common approach to use? And if so, which char is an appropriate delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the syntax of your key value pair. If one of your values is a sentence, then you want to avoid common punctuation.

To be on the safe side, I often use a few letters as the delimiter, to make sure there is no chance of a clash. Something like

```
String key = "key";
String value = "value";

String pair = key + "+DELIM+" + value;
```

That way you've got a very slim chance of your code incorrectly splitting your values. If you suspect there might be a malicious attempt to corrupt the data you're storing by someone working out the delimiter, then you might want to make it a little more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have your key and value, encode it first (such as HEX format) before adding the delimiter between them. On the server side, when you got a message just split with the delimiter and then decode your spitted array back to the original. In this way, you will limit the chance of the key or value matching with the delimiter